# Spherical Gradient Texture on sphere not working

Tags: shader-nodes

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djFe5Du-gtk&t=1s, but i get different result at 5:20. Instead of visible distinction between black and white parts i have this:

[image]

This is how my UV map looks like:

[image]

And nodes:

[image]

Comment: The UV map is irrelevant since you are not using the _UV_ output of the _Texture Coordinate_ node. It's also not necessary to use _UV_ or _Generated_ like suggested in the answer, because there might be cases where you get the same or similar results, but not in general... and the tutorial uses _Object_ and it should work. Since I have no further information on your object it's hard to tell, the only thing I could suspect is that there is something wrong with your mesh. For example, I cannot see any origin point on the selected sphere - have you moved the mesh away from origin in _Edit Mode_?

Answer (score 0):

You texture coordinates are set in `Object` on the TexCoord node. Change it to `UV` or `Generated` instead.

Comment: Why does texture coordinate set to Object work on the tutorial and doesn't work in my project?

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Comment: Actually, that's incorrect. First of all "the person" in the tutorial didn't reference an object (have you watched it?) and second it is not necessary. If you don't specify an object in the _Texture Coordinate_ node, the original object with the material itself will be used. I guess the problem here is something else.

Comment: My sincere apologies.

Comment: You don't have to apologise... I just wanted to provide you with the correct information.